# Linux: How to list all files recursively with path relative to the current path, and do not include current path

Tags: linux, shell

I know there is a question very similar to this one. But please make it clear that I have one more question with this.

I already know that this command,

```
find ./ -name *.txt
```

will find all files recursively in current directory ended with `txt`. However, the result always starts with `./`, which is not desirable for me. I would hope the result not to start with `./`.

That is, for example, if my directory looks like follows:

```
a/b/a.txt
a/b/b.txt
a/b/c.txt
```

If I cd to `a` and run `find ./ -name *.txt`, I get these:

```
./b/a.txt
./b/b.txt
./b/c.txt
```

But what I want are these:

```
b/a.txt
b/b.txt
b/c.txt
```

I would hope some one could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply remove the leading "./" by using a pipe with sed:

```
find . -name "*.txt" |sed s/^\.\\///
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU `find` (which you should since this question is tagged `linux`), then try using the `%P` format with `-printf`

For example, suppose we have these files:

```
$ find . -type f
./a/b/a.txt
./a/b/c.txt
./a/b/b.txt
```

To get the output without the leading `./`, try:

```
$ find . -type f -printf '%P\n'
a/b/a.txt
a/b/c.txt
a/b/b.txt
```

#### Documentation

From `man find`:

> %P
>     File's name with the name of the starting-point under which it
> was found removed.